# ContentVersion FileExtension

Tags: apex, unit-test, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Does anyone know how I can change the FileExtension for a new ContentVersion in a test class?

Im currently trying to create a test class for my ContentDocumentLink Trigger, in which I have an if depending on the FileExtension of the ContentVersion. 
But when creating a ContentVersion I cant fill this field.
When i try to fill it before the insert I just get an error (Field is not writeable: ContentVersion.FileExtension).
I also tried putting the FileExtension in the title, but when testing manually the Title is cut off seperating title and FileExtension.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's determined by the `PathOnClient` field as populated when you create the `ContentVersion`.

As an example, in one of my orgs I uploaded a file called `App.logo.png` through the API, populating its file name in the `PathOnClient` field and `App.logo` in the `Title` field. The system inferred `png` as the value for `FileExtension`.

Answer (score 2):

`ContentVersion's` `FileExtension` and `FileType` fields are not writeable, it is determined by the `PathOnClient`, so you will have to provide value in `PathOnClient` field to determine the extension.

So, your code should be

```
ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
cv.Title = 'Test Image';
cv.PathOnClient = 'Test_Image.jpg';
cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Image Data');
cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
insert cv;
```

Although I was not able to find any documentation which says, that [FileExtension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) field is not **writeable**, but you can get this information by looking at field properties which mentions that this field is neither **creatable** nor **updateable**. **Also, the above documentation just mentions that `FileType` is determined by `PathOnClient` field whereas `FileExtension` is also determined by `PathOnClient`.**

[image: ContentVersion FileExtension]